# Integration with branch point.

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is there a branch point at $x = 0$ for the following function:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(x+a)^3\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: Because the function is discontinuous at $x = 0$?

Comment: Perhaps you are asking about the integrand when you say  "the following function", since you mention a "branch point at $x=0$".  As stated the integral depends on parameter $a$, but not on $x$ (since that is bound as the variable of integration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$ is a multivalued function because of the following definition

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\log(z)}$$

since we have

$$\log(z)=\ln|z|+i\mathrm{arg}(z)$$

Now it is clear that the function is not defined for $z=0$, furthermore because of the discontinuity of the argument at some chosen branch cut the function is analytic on any circular disc by removing a line. The removed line must consist of the discontinuity at $z=0$.

Comment: It is helpful to see how the multivalued square root and logarithm functions can be related, but some care is needed to argue that the multiple branches arise "because of" such a definition.  The square root has only two sheets while the log has countably many.

Comment: In the last line perhaps you meant to say the "removed line must" contain (rather than "consist of") the discontinuity at $z=0$.

Comment: But couldn't you also use the same argument for, say, $f(z)=\frac{1}{x}$? Wouldn't that too, following this rationale, be a branch point?

Comment: @Grtv: It's true the singularity of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ is a simple pole, and it requires no branch cut to make a definition away from the origin.  However the integral of this function is $\log(z)$, and it does require a branch cut to give an extension of the integral away from the origin.  As I commented, your Question is unclear about what function you think has "a branch point".  Is the integrand, or an (indefinite) integral of that?